# Collapse collection of nodes into `n` number of nodes in the directed acyclic graph (DAG)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have a graph of geographical regions and countries, connected with directed `[:PART_OF]` relationships:

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ats4i9

[image]

Let's have random subset of nodes from the graph, special case would be collection of all end nodes (which have no descendants):

```
MATCH (endnode:Geography)-[:PART_OF*]->(parent:Geography)
WHERE NOT (:Geography)-[:PART_OF]->(endnode:Geography)
RETURN endnode.name
// ['Ghana','Nigeria','Iran','Russia','Germany','United States', 'Mexico', 'Brazil']
```

For `n = 1,2,3,..`, how to write a Cypher that collapses the above collection to a collection of exactly `n` nodes, where each node is an ancestor or identical to one or more of the nodes in the initial collection. Moreover, no node in the initial collection can descend from more than one of the nodes in the collapsed collection (no overlaps condition).

For example, if `n=1`, the result for the above initial collection should be `World` node.

If `n=2`, the result should be `['Americas','EMEA']` collection.

If `n=4`, the result should be either `['North America', 'South America & Africa', 'Europe', 'Asia']` or `['Americas', 'Africa', 'Europe', 'Asia']` collection.